# How to prevent handler from stopping its processes when app is not active

Tags: java, android

So I am sending post request to mysql database through a handler and this handler is posting it through a runnable to a async task  Now I want to send this request even if my app is not active so that i can notify the user through notifications When my app is running everything is working fine but when i press the home button or close the app it stops so how can i prevent the handler from stopping its processes even when the app is not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Android Service

Android service is a component that is used to perform operations on the background such as playing music, handle network transactions, interacting content providers etc. It doesn't has any UI (user interface).

The service runs in the background indefinitely even if application is destroyed.

See:

- http://www.javatpoint.com/android-service-tutorial
- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

If you want your user to get some notification messages when new data is available use

- Firebase Cloud Messaging(https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

  or
- Google Cloud Messaging(https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)